# Trying to extract point X and Y from Geodatabase from outside a GIS

Tags: file-geodatabase, format

I have a geodatabase which I would like to integrate with processes outside ArcGIS.  (On our systems Arc is a fairly closed system).

I have managed to connect to the database and perform an extract using OLEDB but cannot get the X,Y coordinates directly. Instead there is a `SHAPE` field which contains binary data:

```
SHAPE
346C0000010C80EB51B88BF81B4152B81E8539A11041
346C0000010CD0A3703D79B41B418FC2F5287A381041
346C0000010CF051B81EB7651B4166666666E50C1841
346C0000010C6066666655061C4148E17A14A4A51041
346C0000010C10AE47E176C31D4185EB51B8423B1641
346C0000010C703D0AD7D6BB134166666666C0C41241
346C0000010C5050FC98D4B813416FF085C96BC61241
346C0000010C400AD7A31C3615417B14AE4790D91141
346C0000010C2085EB5139591441B81E85EB1BAE1341
346C0000010C703D0AD7BA671541CDCCCCCCD50D1441
346C0000010C608FC2F5A36015410AD7A37031881441
346C0000010CF051B81E25211441B81E85EBC62B1441
346C0000010C2085EB51E382154166666666F8211441
346C0000010CC0F5285C1745184152B81E8505B91041
346C0000010C2085EB516B961741713D0AD7CBE91441
```

Does anyone know how this binary data should be interpreted? I assume it is a struct, 1 part declaring it is a point, and 2 other parts declaring the X and Y?

Comment: The Esri file geodatabase API doesn't support OLEDB; are you using an OLEDB wrapper around the Open File Geodatabase drriver? FGDB uses something closer to SDE.ST_Geometry under the hood, but the FGDBAPI exposes shapes in shapefile format. Have you tried decoding this as hex of Well-Known Binary?

Comment: Hi @Vince I think you are correct that we are using the OLEDB wrapper around Open File Geodatabase driver. Sorry, what is "Well-Known Binary"? Like known X and Y values? Would these XYs be stored as double or float?

Comment: WKB is a variant of Well-Known Text, but without the parenthesis. A google on either should expose a link to the other.

Answer (score 1):

So after looking at WKB and realising it wasn't this, I suspected it wasn't anything standard at all... In which case I decided to just brute force it.

Total string length is 44 chars
I noticed the first 12 chars (6 bytes) were fixed data (amongst the data I had) so I ignored these
Remaining chars = 32
Assumed these were split, so I assumed either 4 floats or 2 doubles (2 x 16 chars or 4 x 8 chars)

If I convert 
`80EB51B88BF81B41` and `52B81E8539A11041` into doubles using [this site](https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/) with swap endianness ticked, I get the X and Y!

I have no idea how the suggested website actually converts the data, but I at least have a few more terms to google!

---

Edit: Have actually solved this issue now. 'Reverse Endianness' simply reverses the order in which the bytes are read. so `ABCDEF` --> `EFCDAB`

The language I have been working in is VBA, not sure if this will help anyone else but if it does that's great:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

'Format:
'HEADER       X                Y
'346C0000010C 80EB51B88BF81B41 52B81E8539A11041
'Importantly

Const X_LB As Long = 12
Const Y_LB As Long = 28
Public Function GetX(ByVal shp As String) As Double
    Dim b(1 To 8) As Byte, i As Long, lb As Long
    For i = 1 To 8
      b(i) = CLng("&H" & Mid(shp, X_LB + (i - 1) * 2 + 1, 2))
    Next
    GetX = BytesToDbl(b)
End Function
Public Function GetY(ByVal shp As String) As Double
    Dim b(1 To 8) As Byte, i As Long, lb As Long, s As String
    For i = 1 To 8
      b(i) = CLng("&H" & Mid(shp, Y_LB + (i - 1) * 2 + 1, 2))
    Next
    GetY = BytesToDbl(b)
End Function

'Bytes in IEEE format to Double
Function BytesToDbl(ByRef Bytes() As Byte) As Double
  Dim d As Double
  CopyMemory d, Bytes(LBound(Bytes)), LenB(d)
  BytesToDbl = d
End Function
```

Beware in this algorithm I exploit the fact that VBA also uses the IEEE format for doubles. Other languages might not work in this way, and you might have to parse the byte array more directly.